# Not finding javascript file

Tags: javascript

Not sure why I am getting a 404 error, path to script index.js seems to be correct as it is in the same folder as the html file. I have tried every path that I can think of, not sure what is wrong here.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried different paths and have tried absolute path as well. Thank you for your help.

Update Server.js:
[image]

Comment: You may need to use a relative path: `<script src="index.js" ...`

Comment: Hi Dinh, I still get the same 404 error.

Comment: _Which line of the server code is supposed to handle requests to get the `index.js` file?_ If you don't have one, I'm pretty sure express will return a 404. Also, to avoid downvotes because of presentation, and I see you have one, please review [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on the help center. The bullet point starting "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc" provides a link to a discussion about it on Meta.)

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the folder called static. I can see you add static as a path to show content from here

[image]

So it should go in static

Answer (score -1):

I can see your mistake as per your details you did save your html file and js in only one same you did use the  that is wrong when you will / then browser will associate that from root directory.Means your html file and js file in the same folder you don't need to use that **"/"**. you will just write index.js.
example:

in other case if your your folder and file settings that just that

MyWebProject (Folder)
index.html
js (Folder)
index.js

then you will use that like this:

The `<script>` tag you provided is referencing an external JavaScript file named `function.js` located in the `js` folder. Let me break down the script tag:

```html
<script src="./js/function.js"></script>
```

- `src="./js/function.js"`: This attribute specifies the source (filepath) of the JavaScript file to be included. In this case, it is set to `./js/function.js`, which means the file is located in the `js` folder of the current directory (`.` refers to the current directory).
- `./`: This represents the current directory. So, `./js/` points to the `js` folder in the current directory.
- `function.js`: This is the name of the javascript file to be included.

So, the script tag is telling the browser to load and execute the JavaScript code from the 'function.js' file in the 'js' folder of the current directory. Make sure the file path is correct, and the file `function.js` is in the specified location.